# detect the total added up scroll distance

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to detect the total distance the user scrolled on a website. Therefore I want to add up the scroll distance downwards as well as the scroll distance upwards.

So for example: the user scrolls 150px downwards and scroll back to the top of the page the result should be 300px.

With `window.pageYOffset` I can detect the distance downwards. How can I add both directions up?

// edit:

[image: values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter – `totalOffset`. You need to check current scroll position –  `currOffset`. You need a function that fires on scroll and calculates the distance between current and cached position and that updates the counter and the cached position.

```js
let totalOffset = 0;
let currOffset = window.pageYOffset;
window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  () => {
    let addedOffset = Math.abs(currOffset - window.pageYOffset);
    totalOffset += addedOffset;
    currOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log('the total scroll in px is: ', totalOffset);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<div style="min-height:2000px">
<div>
```

It might not work ideally in SO snippet runner, but it seems to work fine in a browser.

Comment: thanks for your solution! But seems like the other way around. Works fine in SO snippet runner but doesn't work in browser. I've edit a screenshot of the values in the topic above. But I can't find the error in your code.

Comment: Thanks for a feedback. I don't really have a clue why it doesn't work for you, sorry. I've tested it in both Chrome and FF and it seems O.K. The only difference is that i've set the `max-height` to `body` instead of `div`, but I don't think it would be the problem.